# Google Cloud Larvavel project Deploy Error

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I' m trying to deploy laravel project on google cloud but im getting error after deployment.
check url of website https://favorable-tree-268915.ue.r.appspot.com/
Please tell me what im doing wrong

[Please find error in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s63ld.png)

and my app.yaml code is this

```
runtime: php
 env: flex

runtime_config:
        document_root: public

skip_files: -.env

env_variables:
APP_LOG: errorlog
APP_DEBUG: true
APP_KEY: base64:AX0rIpdAVZLDpvoroa+229SeNa9ejRNC80NRHAPyBGo=
STORAGE_DIR: /temp
CACHE_SIRVER: database
SESSION_DRIVER: database
DB_CONNECTION: mysql
DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
DB_PORT: 3306
DB_DATABASE: karma2
DB_USERNAME: karma2
DB_PASSWORD: karma2
DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/favorable-tree-268915:us-east1:karma2"

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "favorable-tree-268915:us-east1:karma2"
```

im getting erros after complete deploy running url please check image above

and this is .env confi

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:AX0rIpdAVZLDpvoroa+229SeNa9ejRNC80NRHAPyBGo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=karma2
DB_USERNAME=karma2
DB_PASSWORD=karma2

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Please help me to figure it out

Comment: Since I can access your application I asume that you were able to fix your issue. Please let us know if you need more help

Comment: But Im still getting error when I upload any file in system it gives unable to create in (folder name), unable to write

Comment: Ok, since that is a different error please post a new question sharing all the details of your code and this error.